# Plotting a hypergeometric function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, special-functions

I am faced with the following expression

$$
-\frac{(1 - a x^{2})^{b/2}}{b} {{}_2F_1} (1, \frac{b}{2}; \frac{c}{2}; 1 - a x^{2}) = - p t
$$

where $ a, b, c, p $ are constant values. Also, $ {{}_2F_1} $ is a hypergeometric function. Now, I am trying to plot $ x $ versus $ t $. I am thankful for any suggestions.

---

I don't know why the code doesn't work in my machine. I am trying a different way by this

`f[a_, b_, c_, p_] := -((1 - a x^2)^(b/2)/b) Hypergeometric2F1[1, b/2, c/2, 1 - a x^2] == -p t; Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[1, 2, 3, p], {p, 1, 2, 3}], {t, -1, 2}, {x, -2, 2}]`

is that correct?

Comment: Try `ContourPlot`?

Comment: @ContourPlot i am not eager to do counter plot. Typical type is better for my purpose

Answer (score 5):

Since we can solve t ,so we can also use `ParametricPlot`

```
Clear["`*"];
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
t = ((1 - a x^2)^(b/2)/b) Hypergeometric2F1[1, b/2, c/2, 1 - a x^2]/p;
ParametricPlot[
 Table[{t, x}, {p, {1, 2, 3}}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {t, -1, 2}, 
 Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is how I'd have done it.

Answer (score 4):

I think [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) works for your case because it can find the curves represented by equations. I do not know what the values of your those constants so I make wild choices in the code below:

```
With[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, p = 4},
  ContourPlot[
    -((1 - a x^2)^(b/2)/b) Hypergeometric2F1[1, b/2, c/2, 1 - a x^2] == -p t,
    {t, -1, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {t, x}
  ]
]
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Suppose that `p` has several values,

```
Block[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ps = {1, 2, 3}, eqns},
  eqns[p_] := -((1 - a x^2)^(b/2)/b) Hypergeometric2F1[1, b/2, c/2, 1 - a x^2] == -p t;
  ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqns /@ ps], {t, -1, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {t, x}, 
    PlotLegends -> StringTemplate["p = ``"] /@ ps
  ]
]
```

[image]

---

How about this unpacked version:

```
Clear[a, b, c, ps, eqns]
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; ps = {1, 2, 3}; 
eqns[p_] := -((1 - a x^2)^(b/2)/b) Hypergeometric2F1[1, b/2, c/2, 1 - a x^2] == -p t;
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqns /@ ps], {t, -1, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {t, x}, 
 PlotLegends -> (StringTemplate["p = ``"] /@ ps)
]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: and how can i do 3 plots in one figure in this case? If i need to consider 3 different values for a parameter and compare the cases.

Comment: @Mehdi By providing 3 equations to `ContourPlot`, I guess. See my update.

Comment: The code you wrote for multi-plots doesn't work in my mathematica. Are you missing some things in the code?

Comment: @Mehdi Just tested, it works on my machine.

Comment: Please take a look at the following answer.

Comment: @Mehdi What error message did your machine issue when trying to run my second piece of codes?

Comment: I think this is the error "Symbol \!\(\"FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$115\"\) does not have a \
value. Dynamic updating may be disabled"

Comment: @Mehdi Try `Module` instead of `Block`, anything else kept untouched.

Comment: still no work. The output is some info about the module

Comment: @Mehdi Then what version of MMA are you using?

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ 12.1.1

Comment: @Mehdi Same as yours. How about the updated unpacked version?

Comment: Your first sample for one plot is working but the second one for different values doesn't work. I think the problem is for some packages we are using for this case

Comment: @Mehdi There is no extra package loaded. And I cannot understand it that the same codes behave differently in the same systems.

Comment: Could you please take a picture form your worksheet of MMA and send to me for comparison since it is very urgent for me? Thanks

Comment: @Mehdi So be it.

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ Really strange. It doesn't work again

Comment: I don't know why but i think my machine only can read the simple orders. For example, it can not read Table, Evaluate etc. I installed it yesterday.